# tar: how to extract a specific version of a file with many updated instances

Tags: tar

I have a tar file which gets updated many times, and there are multiple copies of the same file.  I've found the latest version of the file gets extracted using -x.

For example: I have a save.tar file that contains 3 versions of a.txt:
a.txt version1 "this is not done"
a.txt version2 "this is correct."
a.txt version3 "this is broke."

How do I extract a.txt (the version2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approx. 40 years ago, there was a discussion whether `tar` could get an option to specify the n-th occurence that should be extracted but I am not sure whether this is a good idea.

With a standard `tar` implementation, you could call:

```
tar xvwf archive.tar
```

and then interactively confirm the extraction for the "right" version.

With `star`, there is an additional method:

```
star -xv < archive.tar -find -mtime +some-time-spec -mtime -other-time-spec
```

and use two useful time specifiers to select the "right" version.

See: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html

You of course need to use an additional path name selector in case that the archive file contains more differen filenames. So with a standard `tar`, this becomes:

```
tar xvwf archive.tar a.txt
```

and with star it becomes:

```
star -xv < archive.tar a.txt -find -mtime +some-time-spec -mtime -other-time-spec
```

or:

```
star -xv < archive.tar -find -path a.txt -mtime +some-time-spec -mtime -other-time-spec
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/All-Options.html):

```
--occurrence=n
```

The default for `n` is `1`, or the first occurance of the member.

Comment: @Freddy: Thanks.